# How can I rerun over generator?

Tags: python

I need to print the full time from a certain moment till infinity, but I cant print after one hour..
the program stop at 00:00:59
how can I rerun over the third loop i wrote? I try to zero i but i did not work :(
here is my code:

```
def gen_time():
    sec = gen_secs() #print every second from 0 - 59
    min = gen_minutes() #print every minute from 0 - 59
    hour = gen_hours() #print every hour from 0 - 23
    while True:
        for x in hour:
            for y in min:
                i = 0
                for i in sec:
                    print("i is: " + str(i))
                    yield str(x) + ":" + str(y) + ":" + str(i)
def gen_secs(): # return generator that contain all the possible seconds (0-59)
x = 0
while x < 60:
    while x < 10:
        yield str(0) + str(x)
        x += 1
    yield x
    x += 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Just print every second?

Comment: can you share the gen_sec() method as well? most likely, you need to do a while True loop inside the generator as well to make sure it starts again once it reaches 59.

Comment: yes sure, here is my function:

Answer (score 2):

Generators can only be used once. Just create a new one for each time through the `while` loop.

```
def gen_time():
    while True:
        for x in gen_hours():
            for y in gen_minutes():
                for i in gen_secs():
                    print("i is: " + str(i))
                    yield str(x) + ":" + str(y) + ":" + str(i)
```

However, don't make each component generator have to produce formatted strings; yield integers, and let the `format` method take care of that.

```
from itertools import product

def get_time():
    while True:
        for h, m, s in product(range(24), range(60), range(60)):
            yield f'{h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}'
```

or

```
def gen_seconds():
    yield from (f'{s:02}' for s in range(60))

def gen_minutes():
    yield from (f'{m:02}' for m in range(60))

def gen_hours():
    yield from (f'{h:02}' for m in range(24))

def gen_times():
    while True:
        for h, m, s in product(gen_hours(), gen_minutes(), gen_seconds()):
            yield ':'.join([h, m, s])
```

Comment: ok thanks! how can I do it also in the date? (the year 2020 till infinity, the month - leaf year of not, and the days..